# Access the GWT generated javascript source in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, gwt

In eclipse IDE, how can I see the javascript source code GWT has generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using latest GWT version with Google Plugin for eclipse you 
just need to look under the war/ directory. 
But unless you are compiling with "detailed" or "pretty" option you will not be able to make much of the JavaScript output because by default GWT compiler generates obfuscated code.

See http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile.html for setting compiler options.